# Change boolean in ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, boolean-logic

I want to write Ajax code for my view so that if I change the the check box, the `RegisterSituation` of rows that were chosen is changed in database.

My model class is:

```
public class OstadCourse
{
    [Key]
    public int OstadCourseId { get; set; }
   
    public int OstadId { get; set; }
    public bool RegisterSituation { get; set; }

    public string OstadName { get; set; }
    public string OstadFamily { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
}
```

My view is (I have tried to add Ajax to end of following view, but when I change checked to unchecked, it is send null to controller). How can I write ajax so that change `RegisterSituation` of rows that change?

```
@model IEnumerable<DataLayer.OstadCourse>

@{
   ...
    var courses = Model.Select(x => new { x.CourseId, x.Title }).Distinct();
    var selectedCourseId = Request["selectedCourseId"];
    var filteredCourses = String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedCourseId) ? Model : Model.Where(x => x.CourseId == int.Parse(selectedCourseId));
    ...
}

<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0">
            @Html.DropDownList("selectedCourseId", new SelectList(courses, "CourseId", "Title", selectedCourseId), "-- All --", new { @class = "form-control", style = "padding: 0.375rem .75rem;", onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="gridtable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Family</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in filteredCourses)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="rowCheckbox" name="selectedIDs" value="@item.OstadCourseId" @(item.RegisterSituation ? "checked" : "")  />
                    </td>
                    <td>@item.OstadName</td>
                    <td>@item.OstadFamily</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```